# read column from csv file in terminal ignoring the header

Tags: ksh

I'm writting a simple .ksh file to read a single column from a .csv file and then printing the output to the screen:

```
fname=($(cut -d, -f2 "myfile.csv"))
# loop through these names
for i in ${fname[@]}; 
do echo "$i"
done
```

This works fine but I don't want to return the header row, that is the first row of the file. How would I alter the cut command so that it ignore the first value or string. In this case the header is called 'NAME'. I want to print all of the other rows of this file.

That being said, is it easier to loop through from 2:fname as the code is currently written or is it best to alter the cut command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
fname=($(sed 1d myfile.csv | cut -d, -f2))
```

Alternately, the index of the first element of the array is 0: to start the loop at index 1:

```
for i in "${fname[@]:1}"; do
```

Demo:

```
$ a=(a b c d e f)
$ echo "${a[@]:1}"
b c d e f
```

Note, you should always put the array expansion in double quotes.