# reading two word strings as single string with cut or awk in terminal

Tags: ksh

I have a question will follows from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222074/read-column-from-csv-file-in-terminal-ignoring-the-header) one. I'm writting a simple .ksh file to read a single column from a .csv file and then printing the output to the screen:

```
fname=($(sed 1d myfile.csv | cut -d, -f2))
# loop through these names
for i in ${fname[@]}; 
do echo "$i"
done
```

The issue that I have now is that I would like each entry in fname to be a string that can be two words. For example, if the csv file has a column

```
data
data 1
data 2
```

I would like fname to be:

```
data
data 1
data 2
```

where it is currently returning:

```
data
data
1
data
2
```

Is it possible to adapt my code to do this?

A version I have using awk is:

```
fname=($(awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}' "myfile"))
# loop through these names
for i in ${fname[@]}; 
do echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Can you accept alternate solutions? Good luck.

Comment: Yes, any solution is welcomed. As long as it also skips the header of the file as the previous method does.

Comment: Done with explanatory edits. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this might be a problem. The issue is the way you're populating the array:

```
fname=($(sed 1d myfile.csv | cut -d, -f2))
```

The elements of the array are "data", "data", "1", "data", "2" -- you've already lost the "words".

Bash has a nice `mapfile` command to read a file or the output of a command and store the lines into an array. For ksh you may have to do

```sh
fname=()
sed 1d myfile.csv | while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 rest; do
    fname+=( "$col2" )
done
```

Note that it is critically important to quote the array in the for loop (I did mention this in my answer to the other question):

```sh
for i in "${fname[@]}"; do
# .......^...........^ ............ quotes here are required
    echo "$i"
    # ...^..^ ..................... here too
done
```

Answer (score 1):

**awk answer**

```
$ cat myData
c1,data,c3
c1,data 1,c3
c1,data 2,c3

# demo-solution
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $1, "\"" $2 "\"", $3 }' myDat

**output**

c1,"data",c3
c1,"data 1",c3
c1,"data 2",c3
```

If you really only need the 2nd field, just remove `$1,` and `, $3` from the print line, i.e.

```
#exact output solution
awk -F, '{print "\"" $2 "\"" }' myDat

**output**

"data"
"data 1"
"data 2"
```

This answer can also be used "in-line" reading from a pipe, like

```
  youCSVproducingProcess | awk '......'
```

---

**orig answer**

```
echo "c1,data,c3
c1,data 1,c3
c1,data 2,c3" \
| while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3 ; do
echo "\"$col2\""
done
```

**output**

```
"data"
"data 1"
"data 2"
```

Is the basic idea.

You can create a script that processes a file with

```
#!/bin/ksh
case $# in 0 ) echo "usage: myScript InputFile" ; exit 1 ;; esac
inFile="$1"
while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3 ; do
    echo "\"$col2\""
done < "$inFile"
```

The key items here are the `while ... done < "$inFile"`, `IFS=,` and `read col1 col2 col3`.

The `while` loop when coupled with `read var1 var2` (or `read line`) is a standard solution to reading thru a file 1 line at a time. Note that this relies on the standard of data that is all represented on 1 line. Data with multiple columns that have line breaks inside the column require a different approach.

(`read line` is just a convention, it can be any valid variable name, same with `col1` or `var1`; `my1Var` would also work and many others).

To make `read line` more useful, `read` understands that if there are more than 1 variable listed ('col1 col2 col3), it will take the std-in (provided implicitly by the `while` loop), and read that line of data, breaking it up into `n` number of fields.

The default field separator for `read` is space-or-tab-char. (Skipping over some details here, you pedants out there ;-) ). Using `IFS=,` says read the line and split the fields by the `,` char. With 2 commas, you get 3 fields, as ilustrated in my sample data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, lthough this does not work in the code that this feeds into. Do you know of a way of doing this using either cut or awk?